# web3 on react-native : Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: web3js

using `web3@1.0.0-beta.33` and `react-native@0.59.10`, because latest `web3` have install issue on `react-native`, after deep research `1.0.0-beta.33` is suitable on `react-native`

```
const web3 = new Web3("https://mainnet.infura.io:443"); 
var count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(this.state.selectedWallet.publicaddress);
var contractdata = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, SensitiveInfo.tokencontract);
var rawTransaction = {
    "from": this.state.selectedWallet.publicaddress,
    "nonce": count,
    "gasPrice": 4500000000,
    "gas": web3.utils.toHex("519990"),
    "gasLimit":web3.utils.toHex("519990"),
    "to": SensitiveInfo.tokencontract,
    "value": "0x0",
    "data": contractdata.methods.transfer(this.state.recipientaddress,web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether')).encodeABI(),
    "chainId": 0x01
};
var privKey = new Buffer(this.state.selectedWallet.privatekey,'hex');
var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);
tx.sign(privKey);
var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), (err, hash) =>{
  if (!err) //SUCCESS
      console.log(hash);
  else
      console.log(err);
});
```

}

#### Note

1. the same code base use in web are work, but `web3@1.2.1`
2. I can very confirmed the **from** address have enough token and gas
3. have do research said change all hex to number, like `gas` , `gasLimit`, `value` and `chainId`

Comment: How much ether do you have in `this.state.selectedWallet.publicaddress`?

Comment: @goodvibration enough to do the transaction , because it work in web

Comment: Well, maybe there isn't enough after you've executed it already. In any case, I recommend using beta-34, which I know to be stable. Beta-37 is also known to be stable (version 1.2.0 is based on it; not sure about version 1.2.1). Other beta versions are not stable AFAIK.

Comment: @goodvibration just tried what you suggest 34 and 37, 34 have exact same problem as question say, 37 have same problem when install `1.2.1` , as this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613819/web3-in-react-native-cannot-read-property-getreader

Comment: @goodvibration is there any other that web3 to sendSignedTransaction ? i would like to make a try

Comment: Yes, will post it as an answer...

Comment: BTW, `gas` and `gasLimit` are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With web3 1.0.0-beta.34, you can try this:

```
async function send(transaction, privateKey) {
    const options = {
        to      : transaction._parent._address,
        data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
        gasPrice: "4500000000",
        gas     : "519990",
        value   : "0"
    };
    const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, privateKey);
    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
    return receipt;
}
```

Usage example:

```
const to      = this.state.recipientaddress;
const value   = web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether");
const key     = this.state.selectedWallet.privatekey;
const receipt = await send(contractdata.methods.transfer(to, value), key);
```

Comment: after some try , i find out it was my private key issue, but web3 doesn't error me the correct way, thats why i keep stuck on gas and value, anyway thanks for inform me to use 34 for stable version. Although your answer i haven't try, but consider it might help others, so I will mark as correct ! Thanks a lot !